# Unable to connect to S3 using BOTO

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am trying to connect S3 using boto.

I am able to list S3 bucket details using s3 CLI commands but boto is unable to establish connection

boto version: 2.46.1
Python Version: 2.7.12

My code is as follows and the `error message is "[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"`

```
#!/home/python-workdir/python-2.7.12/bin/python
import os, sys
import math
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.s3.connection

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
Bucketname = 'bucket/private/im/poc/master/1/testbucket'

conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2',
       aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
       aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
       calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
       )
print "conn success"
bucket = conn.get_bucket(Bucketname)
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly well for me, against my own bucket. `Connection reset by peer` is usually an indication of network problems. If it happens all the time, check whether you are going through a VPN or whether something is denying your API request through the network. Try it from a different network to narrow-down the cause (eg from home vs work, on different VLANs, via phone tether, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation John, I had a similar though. Going to try in my personal acc

Comment: `Bucketname = 'bucket/private/im...` *what?* Buckets can't have `/` in their names.  I don't know what value this is, but it isn't a bucket name.

Comment: Yes, I then had to separate the bucket and folders separately. Thanks @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein
Yes, the code works perfectly in my personal account. Should be something to do with networking stuff playing up in the middle in corporate acc.

Comment: Is there a way to get how long it took to upload a file using boto3 upload_file() ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've play with AWS CLI, why don't you start changing your code to boto3, use the ~/.aws/* credentials setup ?

First, if you use aws cli to do this, this include the prefix

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/private/im/poc/master/1/testbucket
```

So the code should be something like this

```
import boto3
Bucketname = 'bucket'
prefix = '/private/im/poc/master/1/testbucket'
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
mybucket = s3.Bucket(Bucketname)
all_object = mybucket.objects.all()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get how long it took to upload a file using boto3 upload_file() ?

Comment: @suj : that will be another question about diagnostic uploading speed.